# How to restructure object array to nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The structure of an object array looks like this:

```
[
    { _id: "id1", metadata: { data: ["somedata1"], link: [] } }
    { _id: "id2", metadata: { data: ["somedata2"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } }
    { _id: "id3", metadata: { data: ["somedata3"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } }
    { _id: "id4", metadata: { data: ["somedata4"] } }
]
```

As you can see, there is an optional `link` key, which connects two objects. Now I need to convert the object to array elements, which merges the connected datasets. So the result should look like this:

```
[
    [
        { _id: "id1", metadata: { data: ["somedata1"], link: [] } }
    ],
    [
        { _id: "id2", metadata: { data: ["somedata2"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } },
        { _id: "id3", metadata: { data: ["somedata3"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } }
    ],
    [
        { _id: "id4", metadata: { data: ["somedata4"] } }
    ]
]
```

I think I would iterate through all objects, but I don't know how to merge the linked objects into one array element without getting duplicates.

```
const result = []
data.map(d => {
    if (!d.metadata.link?.length)
        result.push([d])
    else 
        result.push(
            data.getFiles.filter((item) => d.metadata.link.indexOf(item._id) !== -1)
        )
    // but this would result in a duplicate array, as id2 and id3 have the same link content
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to loop on an array you can directly use `array.forEach`

An idea can be to just add an if before push in result array to check if data have already been added for sample with `array.some`

```
 if (!result.some(oneArr => oneArr.some(oneData => oneData._id === d._id)))
```

```js
const data = [
    { _id: "id1", metadata: { data: ["somedata1"], link: [] } },
    { _id: "id2", metadata: { data: ["somedata2"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } },
    { _id: "id3", metadata: { data: ["somedata3"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } },
    { _id: "id4", metadata: { data: ["somedata4"] } }
];


const result = [];
data.forEach(d => {
    if (!d.metadata.link?.length) {
        result.push([d])
    } else {
      if (!result.some(oneArr => oneArr.some(oneData => oneData._id === d._id)))
        result.push(
            data.filter((item) => d.metadata.link.indexOf(item._id) !== -1)
        )
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below way object will not get duplicate. data will group as `link` values. This approach does n't have much complexity. It will be `O(N)`

I hope this is what you're looking for.

```js
const data = [
    { _id: "id1", metadata: { data: ["somedata1"], link: [] } },
    { _id: "id2", metadata: { data: ["somedata2"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } },
    { _id: "id3", metadata: { data: ["somedata3"], link: ["id2", "id3"] } },
    { _id: "id4", metadata: { data: ["somedata4"] } }
]

const result = data.reduce((acumD, d) => {
       const link = d?.metadata?.link;

        if (!link) {

            if (acumD['NONE']) {
                acumD['NONE'].push(d)
            } else {
                acumD['NONE'] = [d];
            }
        } else if (link.length === 0) {
            if (acumD['EMPTY']) {
                acumD['EMPTY'].push(d)
            } else {
                acumD['EMPTY'] = [d];
            } 
        } else {
            const linkString = link.join(',');
             if (acumD[linkString]) {
                acumD[linkString].push(d)
             } else {
                acumD[linkString] = [d];
             } 
        }

        return acumD;
}, {});


console.log('result', Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic grouping function:

```
function groupBy(a, fn) {
    let m = new Map

    for (let x of a) {
        let key = fn(x)
        if (!m.has(key))
            m.set(key, [])
        m.get(key).push(x)
    }

    return [...m.values()]
}
```

Applied to the problem at hand:

```
result = groupBy(
    data,
    x => JSON.stringify(x.metadata.link))
```

produces the desired result.